# Pandas - Create Column on the fly based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

Suppose that I have a data frame as below

```
+------------+-------+
|    Date    | Price |
+------------+-------+
| 25/08/2021 |    30 |
| 24/08/2021 |    20 |
| 23/08/2021 |    50 |
| 20/08/2021 |    10 |
| 19/08/2021 |    24 |
| 18/08/2021 |    23 |
| 17/08/2021 |    22 |
| 16/08/2021 |    10 |
+------------+-------+
```

The above data frame can be generated using below code

```
data = {'Date':['2021-08-25', '2021-08-24', '2021-08-23', '2021-08-20',
                '2021-08-19', '2021-08-18', '2021-08-17', '2021-08-16'],
        'Price':[30, 20, 50, 10, 24, 23, 22, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a column `weight` on the fly based on a scalar `phi`.
Suppose `phi = 0.95` the weight at `t` would be `1-phi` i.e. at `2021-08-25` value for `weight` would be `0.05`. For remaining dates the value would be `W_t+1 * phi`. So for date `2021-08-24` value for `weight` would be `0.05*0.95=0.0475`

**Expected Output**

```
+------------+-------+-------------+
|    Date    | Price |   Weight    |
+------------+-------+-------------+
| 2021-08-25 |    30 |        0.05 |
| 2021-08-24 |    20 |      0.0475 |
| 2021-08-23 |    50 |    0.045125 |
| 2021-08-20 |    10 |  0.04286875 |
| 2021-08-19 |    24 | 0.040725313 |
| 2021-08-18 |    23 | 0.038689047 |
| 2021-08-17 |    22 | 0.036754595 |
| 2021-08-16 |    10 | 0.034916865 |
+------------+-------+-------------+
```

What would be the vectorized approach to create column `weight` on the fly?

Comment: What is `W_t` ?

Comment: Is it `W_t + 1 * phi`, or `(W_t + 1) * phi`? Your example even suggests `W_t * phi`, if `W_t` is the previous cell value.

Comment: `(1-phi) * 0.95 ** np.arange(len(df))` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: `weight` for most recent date (i.e. 2021-08-25) is calculated using `1-phi` remaining dates (i.e. 2021-08-24 and prior) are calculated using formula `(W_t + 1) * phi`.

Comment: My first comment remains unanswered though. In partciular because the formula `(W_t + 1) * phi` doesn't match your example of `0.05 * 0.95` (unless `W_t` here is -0.95).

Comment: `W_t =  1 - phi` and `W_t-1 = W_t * phi` where `t` is max date

Comment: Right: so `W_(t+1)` and the like: the whole `t+1` or `t-1` is a subscript. That was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the example output values given:

```
df['Weight'] = (1 - phi) * phi ** np.arange(len(df))
```

```
         Date  Price    Weight
0  2021-08-25     30  0.050000
1  2021-08-24     20  0.047500
2  2021-08-23     50  0.045125
3  2021-08-20     10  0.042869
4  2021-08-19     24  0.040725
5  2021-08-18     23  0.038689
6  2021-08-17     22  0.036755
7  2021-08-16     10  0.034917
```

(The output values are shown rounded, which is Pandas' standard.)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`numpy.logspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html#numpy.logspace) or [`numpy.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html) to build the geometric series:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date':['2021-08-25', '2021-08-24', '2021-08-23', '2021-08-20',
                '2021-08-19', '2021-08-18', '2021-08-17', '2021-08-16'],
        'Price':[30, 20, 50, 10, 24, 23, 22, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

phi = 0.95
df['Weight'] = np.geomspace(1-phi, (1-phi)*phi**(len(df)-1), num=len(df))

print(df)
#          Date  Price    Weight
# 0  2021-08-25     30  0.050000
# 1  2021-08-24     20  0.047500
# 2  2021-08-23     50  0.045125
# 3  2021-08-20     10  0.042869
# 4  2021-08-19     24  0.040725
# 5  2021-08-18     23  0.038689
# 6  2021-08-17     22  0.036755
# 7  2021-08-16     10  0.034917
```

Using `numpy.logspace` instead of `numpy.geomspace`:

```py
from math import log
start = log(1-phi, phi)
df['Weight'] = np.logspace(start, start+len(df)-1, num=len(df), base=phi)
```

Comment: The Weight values don't match those in the example output.